# Find the value of key from JSON with Shell Script without using jq

Tags: json, shell, loops

I am looking to read a JSON file using shell script and getting Id based on the name attribute and store it in a variable without using "jq". Please suggest how it can be done. The json looks like:

```
{
          "elements": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "internalId": "AA",
              "name": "SampleService",
            },
            {
              "id": "2",
              "internalId": "BB",
              "name": "Loan_Evaluation",
            },
            {
              "id": "3",
              "internalId": "CC",
              "name": "Miniloan Service",
            }
          ],`
     }
```

Comment: Why do you want to not use jq? Is it because the input JSON is not well-formed?

Comment: [Here's good info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955555/2834978) and several answers. Also, take some time to read [how to ask on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: _"using shell script"_ means you want to parse JSON with just native Bash tools? Good luck with that.